# Why is 'bool' keyword syntax highlighted in Xcode configured for C89?

Tags: c, xcode, boolean, c89

I read that booleans in C first came with C99. Now I wonder why bool nevertheless gets colored by Xcode's syntax highlighting, or what you call it...
When one searches "dial" in the build settings in Xcode, the "Language Dialect" pops up, and there I "dial-in" the C89 standard, and still bool gets colored.

Why is that?

I also read this:
[Using boolean values in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921539/using-boolean-values-in-c)

and I see how they did it, but I also don't understand how Example 3 and 4 works...

```
Option 3
typedef int bool;
enum { false, true };

Option 4
typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0
```

Note: I don't understand how the `typedef int bool;` could in anyway be connected with the line `enum { false, true };`.

Why is xcode with C89 not ignoring the bool keyword?
How do the examples work?

Comment: I think it's likely that Xcode's syntax highlighter is just not paying attention to the "language dialect" setting.  Do your "option 3" and "option 4" _compile_ in C89 mode? They should, as long as you don't `#include <stdbool.h>`.

Comment: Xcode is an IDE and not a compiler. It has its own rules.

Comment: Also, you should be aware that `bool`, `true`, and `false` are _not_ keywords even in the latest version of the C standard. C99 added a genuine boolean _type_ and the keyword `_Bool`, but programs that define `bool`, `true`, and `false` as they like are still valid in C99 and later (again, as long as they don't include `stdbool.h`).  This is an intentional difference from C++.

Comment: hey! i didn't try Option 3 and 4 since i don't understand how the 
" typedef int bool; " could in anyway be connected with the line 
" enum { false, true }; "

Comment: @Nickname Does it help if I tell you that the constants defined by an `enum` declaration have type `int`?

Comment: i'm not concerned about the latest C version, only C89...

Comment: @zwol i know they are int's but still its confusing.. i mean why isn't there a bool instead of enum later on, when it got typedef-ined a line before??
i take Option 2 then

Comment: `typedef int bool; bool { true, false };` would not do what is needed...

Comment: `typedef enum bool_t`
`{`
    `b_false = 0,`
    `b_true  = 1`
`} bool;`

is what i use, and these flags -Wall `-pedantic -std=c89` as well, and still it gets _colored_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax highlighting is an approximation used by `XCode`; it's not guaranteed to follow any standard. Not to say the [syntax highlighting in XCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting#History_and_limitations) is not fairly advanced, but it would be very difficult to tell without compiling for a specific standard, what the symbols mean exactly, in real-time.

In the case of Option 3, it's performing an [implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) from an anonymous `enum` to an `int`. Since they are compatible types, it is "always a no-op and does not change the representation." The [default enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434105/are-default-enum-values-in-c-the-same-for-all-compilers) values for `{ false, true }` are `{ 0, 1 }`, so this should result in the same assembler output. This answer [has the order of preference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1921557/2472827) when one doesn't know what to pick.